# Passing Properties as Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass properties from my `Game` class into a method called `Compete`. I am calling the `Compete` method in my controller, but can't access these parameters.

> **Question:** How can I pass `UserGuess` and `ComputerGuess` properties into my `Compete` method

**Model**

```
namespace RockPaperScissors.Models

{
    public class Game
    {
        public string UsersGuess { get; set; }
        public string ComputersGuess { get; set; }
        public string Winner { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**GameLogic**

```
namespace RockPaperScissors.Business
{
    public class GameLogic
    {
        public string Outcome { get; set; }

        public string Compete(string userInput, string computerInput)
        {
           // Logic Here

            return Outcome;
        }
    }
}
```

**GameController**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RockPaperScissors.Business;
using RockPaperScissors.Models;

namespace RockPaperScissors.Controllers
{
    public class GameController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var model = new Game
             {
                 Winner = new GameLogic().Compete(UserGuess, ComputerGuess)
             };

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**ComputerLogic**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RockPaperScissors.Business
{
    public class ComputerLogic
    {
        public string ComputersGuess()
        {
            var options = new List<string> { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };

            var randomizer = new Random();
            var random = randomizer.Next(options.Count);

            return options[random];
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using RockPaperScissors.Models
@model Game

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Games";
}

<h2>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Game"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter your decision:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UsersGuess, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Guess" />
    </div>
}

<h3>Computers Guess: </h3> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ComputersGuess)

<h2>Winner: </h2> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Winner)
```

Comment: You are trying to access properties of Game object _before_  it is created.

Comment: You have a form which makes a POST so you need a method marked with `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Index(Game model)` Having `DisplayFor(m => m.ComputersGuess)` and `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Winner)` in that view makes so sense. You need to POST the `UsersGuess` and redirect to another view that displays the `ComputersGuess` and `Winner`

Comment: Hey @StephenMuecke, thanks for your response. However, I'm not sure how this allows me to pass `UserGuess` and `ComputersGuess` into my method `Compete`

Comment: @alexm, I understand what your saying, but don't know how to implement it. Could you expand?

Comment: @CodeChaser, You post back the value of `UserGuess` and pass that to a GET method. In that GET method, you initialize a new instance of `Game`, set the `UserGuess` property, set the `ComputersGuess` (by calling the appropriate method) and then set the `Winner` property (by calling the appropriate method), and finally return a view with displays the `UserGuess`, ComputerGuess` and `Winner` (and that view might have a 'Play again' link which redirects back to the initial method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You over complicating it with having the logic in separate methods. You can simplify this by including the logic in your model

```
public class Game
{
    public Game()
    {
      Options = new List<string>(){ "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
    }
    [Display(Name = "Select you guess")]
    [Required]
    public string UsersGuess { get; set; }
    public string ComputersGuess { get; set; }
    public string Winner { get; set; }
    public List<string> Options { get; private set; }
    public void Play()
    {
      var random = new Random().Next(Options .Count);
      ComputersGuess = Options[random];
      Winner = // your logic here (compare UserGuess and ComputerGuess)
    }
}
```

Then create separate methods for displaying the form for the user selection, and for displaying the results

```
public ActionResult Play()
{
  Game model = new Game();
  return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Play(Game model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Result", new { userChoice = model.UserGuess });
}
public ActionResult Result(string userChoice)
{
  Game model = new Game() { UsersGuess = userChoice };
  if (!model.Options.Contains(userChoice))
  {
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Your error message here");
  }
  model.Play();
  return View(model);
}
```

Play.cshtml

```
@model Game
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m =>m.UsersGuess)</div>
  foreach(string option in Model.Options)
  {
    <label>
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UsersGuess, option, new { id = "" })
      <span>@option</span>
    </label>
  }
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UsersGuess)
  <input type="submit" value="Play" />
}
```

Result.cshtml

```
@model Game
<div><span>You guessed</span><span>@Model.UserGuess</span></div>
<div><span>The computer guessed</span><span>@Model.ComputersGuess</span></div>
<div><span>And the winner is</span><span>@Model.Winner</span></div>
<div>@Html.ActionLink("Play again", "Play")</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. I'll give it a try tomorrow and if it works, I'll mark it as the answer. Question about over complicating... The reason I was putting things into multiple files is to promote Object Oriented Programming; shouldn't some of the code you've written be put into different classes instead of grouping it together? The goal of my little programming adventure was to practice MVC and OOP, am I thinking about OOP incorrectly?

Comment: Notreally. Its logic specifically related to the `Game` class. But alternatively you could have a service with a method say `public void Play(Game game)` which sets the `ComputersGuess` and `Winner` properties. (and of course all this logic is relatively simple so you could do it all in the browser if you wanted to and avoid leaving the page)

Comment: Thanks so much @StephenMuecke, this did the trick. Would you mind explaining the methods in the controller? I'm a little confused on what each of these are doing.

Comment: Not sure which bits your not understandng. `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` checks that the user has selected on option (if not a `ModelState` error is added because `UsersGuess` has the `[Required]` attribute) and returns the view with and error message. If there are no errors, the `return RedirectToAction(..)` redirects to the `Result()` method and passes the selected option to it.

Comment: In the `Result()` method, an new `Game` is initialized and the `UserGuess` property is set based on the value passed to it. The `if (!model.Options.Contains(userChoice))` line checks that the choice is valid (in case someone just navigates to the method without passing a valid choice - e.g. `/Results/Knife`). Finally the `Play()` method is called to set the `ComputerGuess` and `Winner` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You must first assign values to your model.

```
var model = new Game()
{
ComputersGuess = "someVal",
UserGuess = "anotherVal",
Winner = new GameLogic().Compete(UserGuess, ComputerGuess)
};
```

You should also make `Compete` `static`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how does this work if I get the users input from my view and the Computers value is randomly generated from ComputerLogic class?